# Is it possible to use different colors for focused and selected state on uitabbaritems at tvOS?

Tags: uitabbar, tvos, uitabbaritem, uiappearance

In our tvOS app we have a customised tabbar. now additionally we want to change the background color of the focused/selected item. When I do by `tabBarAppearance.selectionIndicatorTintColor = .purple`, it changes focused and selected states to purple(while without that line code we do have different colors or at least different opacities).

no custom color focused:
[image: no custom color focused]
no custom color selected
[image: no custom color selected]
custom color focused
[image: custom color focused]
custom color selected
[image: custom color selected]

Is it possible to use different colors for focused and selected (like I did for the item text, as you can see on the screen shots)?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Rudrank Riyam. Yes, I did and below is the code, in my own answer to this. Thanks for reminding me to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed that by setting the the `standardAppearance` of the tab bar each time the focus changes in my `UITabBarController`. The relevant code looks like this (the initial setup of appearance is only posted for completeness):

```swift
    // setting up standard appearance for the first time
    private func setupTabbarAppearance() {
        let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        //...
        tabBarAppearance.selectionIndicatorTintColor = .focusedBackgroundColor // focused items
        //...
        let itemAppearance = UITabBarItemAppearance()
        //...
        itemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes[.foregroundColor] = .normalTextColor // used for focused AND non-focused items, 
                                                                                       // when the whole tabbar is focused
        //...
        itemAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes[.foregroundColor] = .selectedTextColor // used for the selected item,
                                                                                           // wen tabbar is not focused
        // ...
        tabBarAppearance.inlineLayoutAppearance = itemAppearance
        tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        tabBar.setNeedsLayout()
    }

    private func setTabBarIndicatorColor(tabBarFocused: Bool) {
        let currentAppearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
        // here is where the color is set
        currentAppearance.selectionIndicatorTintColor = tabBarFocused ? .focusedBackgroundColor : .selectedBackgroundColor
        tabBar.standardAppearance = currentAppearance
    }

    // change appearance each time, when focus changes in tabbar controller
    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if isTabbarInHierarchy(view: context.nextFocusedView) {
            setTabBarIndicatorColor(tabBarFocused: true)
        } else {
            setTabBarIndicatorColor(tabBarFocused: false)
        }
        super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)
    }

    private func isTabbarInHierarchy(view: UIView?) -> Bool {
        guard let view = view else {return false}
        if view == tabBar {
            return true
        }
        return isTabbarInHierarchy(view: view.superview)
    }
```